# Как управлять DVD приводом?

Tags: windows, c++

Как управлять DVD приводом?

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста, что вы имеете в виду под управлением приводом

Comment: Вероятно, как программно открывать и закрывать дисковод. Классика же :) Кстати, гуглится замечательно.

Answer (score 2):

В определенных пределах (например, для начала воспроизведения, паузы, останова и т.п.) вы можете использовать вызов функции Windows API [mciSendString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757161(v=vs.85).aspx).